# android: return to a activity when finishing sending an email

Tags: android

I have a mail sending program. There are two activities in the programme. The mail function is in the second activity. How can I go back to the first activity when finishing sending email? 
  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call finish(); in your email activity once it has completed sending

Comment: i tried this, but it will return to the privious activity but the first(original) one.

Comment: I don't follow you. The activity stack should follow the order you've launched things in. So if you launch Main activity -> Second activity and call finish on your Second activity, it should return to Main activity.

Comment: i add dismiss() at the end of dialog, soluted!